# How can I make an incremented by 1 serial based on multiple conditions Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, increment

Edit #1 : The code could contain random letters and numbers like "A123BC56xa"

Edit #2 : I tried this `subquery` but it gave me `Syntax Error`

```
SELECT DocDtls.Warehouse, Transactions.Code, DocDtls.zDate, Transactions.ID, Transactions.QtyIn, Transactions.QtyOut, Transactions.BalanceAfter, (SELECT Count("*") FROM Transactions AS B WHERE  B.[ID]<A.[ID] And B.[Warehouse] = A.[Warehouse] And B.[Code] = A.[Code])+1 AS Serial
FROM DocDtls INNER JOIN Transactions ON DocDtls.DocNum = Transactions.DocNum
ORDER BY DocDtls.Warehouse, Transactions.Code, DocDtls.zDate, Transactions.ID As A;
```

I have this query

```
SELECT DocDtls.Warehouse, DocDtls.zDate, Transactions.Code, Transactions.ID, Transactions.QtyIn, Transactions.QtyOut, Transactions.BalanceAfter
FROM DocDtls INNER JOIN Transactions ON DocDtls.DocNum = Transactions.DocNum
ORDER BY DocDtls.Warehouse, Transactions.Code, DocDtls.zDate, Transactions.ID;
```

This is the current query result :

```
Warehouse | zDate   |   ID  |   Code    |   QtyIn   |QtyOut |   BalanceAfter
MainWh  |   20-03-2022  |   7   |   00001   |   5000|   0   |   0
MainWh  |   21-03-2022  |   8   |   00001   |   0   |   1000|   0
MainWh  |   20-03-2022  |   9   |   00002   |   7000|   0   |   0
MainWh  |   21-03-2022  |   10  |   00002   |   0   |   2500|   0
Wh1     |   21-03-2022  |   1   |   00001   |   1000|   0   |   0
Wh1     |   25-04-2022  |   5   |   00001   |   0   |   250 |   0
Wh1     |   25-04-2022  |   5   |   00001   |   0   |   300 |   0
Wh1     |   21-03-2022  |   2   |   00002   |   2500|   0   |   0
Wh1     |   25-04-2022  |   6   |   00002   |   0   |   500 |   0
```

I need to add a serial column like ID  but incremented by 1 based on `Code` And `Warehouse` and the result should be Like

```
Warehouse | zDate   |   ID  |   Code    |   QtyIn   |QtyOut |   BalanceAfter|   Serial
MainWh  |   20-03-2022  |   7   |   00001   |   5000|   0   |   0|               1  
MainWh  |   21-03-2022  |   8   |   00001   |   0   |   1000|    0|              2  
MainWh  |   20-03-2022  |   9   |   00002   |   7000|   0   |    0|              1  
MainWh  |   21-03-2022  |   10  |   00002   |   0   |   2500|   0|               2  
Wh1     |   21-03-2022  |   1   |   00001   |   1000|   0   |   0    |           1  
Wh1     |   25-04-2022  |   5   |   00001   |   0   |   250 |   0|               2  
Wh1     |   25-04-2022  |   5   |   00001   |   0   |   300 |   0|               3  
Wh1     |   21-03-2022  |   2   |   00002   |   2500|   0   |   0    |           1
Wh1     |   25-04-2022  |   6   |   00002   |   0   |   500 |   0|               2
```

I'm using sqlserver 2014 , Thanks in advance .

Comment: which database are you using, does it support window function
?

Comment: I don't know if my database supports this , I use SqlServerExpress 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server 2014 is very old, and should be urgently replaced.

You can use window functions like row_number to achieve your goal

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DocDtls 
>     ([Warehouse] varchar(6), [zDate] varchar(10), [ID] int, [Code] int, [QtyIn] int, [QtyOut] int, [BalanceAfter] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO DocDtls 
>     ([Warehouse], [zDate], [ID], [Code], [QtyIn], [QtyOut], [BalanceAfter])
> VALUES
>     ('MainWh', '20-03-2022', 7, 00001, 5000, 0, 0),
>     ('MainWh', '21-03-2022', 8, 00001, 0, 1000, 0),
>     ('MainWh', '20-03-2022', 9, 00002, 7000, 0, 0),
>     ('MainWh', '21-03-2022', 10, 00002, 0, 2500, 0),
>     ('Wh1', '21-03-2022', 1, 00001, 1000, 0, 0),
>     ('Wh1', '25-04-2022', 5, 00001, 0, 250, 0),
>     ('Wh1', '25-04-2022', 5, 00001, 0, 300, 0),
>     ('Wh1', '21-03-2022', 2, 00002, 2500, 0, 0),
>     ('Wh1', '25-04-2022', 6, 00002, 0, 500, 0)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

9 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT *,
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY [Warehouse],[Code] ORDER BY [ID]) as Serial
> FROM DocDtls
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Warehouse | zDate      | ID | Code | QtyIn | QtyOut | BalanceAfter | Serial
> :-------- | :--------- | -: | ---: | ----: | -----: | -----------: | -----:
> MainWh    | 20-03-2022 |  7 |    1 |  5000 |      0 |            0 |      1
> MainWh    | 21-03-2022 |  8 |    1 |     0 |   1000 |            0 |      2
> MainWh    | 20-03-2022 |  9 |    2 |  7000 |      0 |            0 |      1
> MainWh    | 21-03-2022 | 10 |    2 |     0 |   2500 |            0 |      2
> Wh1       | 21-03-2022 |  1 |    1 |  1000 |      0 |            0 |      1
> Wh1       | 25-04-2022 |  5 |    1 |     0 |    250 |            0 |      2
> Wh1       | 25-04-2022 |  5 |    1 |     0 |    300 |            0 |      3
> Wh1       | 21-03-2022 |  2 |    2 |  2500 |      0 |            0 |      1
> Wh1       | 25-04-2022 |  6 |    2 |     0 |    500 |            0 |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=47be503b60be9648f681baadffb1587c)*

Answer (score 0):

If the Code column is always in this format '00001', '00002', '00101', etc., you can use a cast.

```
SELECT DocDtls.Warehouse, DocDtls.zDate, Transactions.Code, Transactions.ID, Transactions.QtyIn, Transactions.QtyOut, Transactions.BalanceAfter
FROM DocDtls INNER JOIN Transactions ON DocDtls.DocNum = Transactions.DocNum
ORDER BY DocDtls.Warehouse, Transactions.Code, DocDtls.zDate, Transactions.ID, CAST(Transactions.Code AS INT) AS Serial;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , No it could contain letters this is just an example to clear my point .

Comment: @CsharpNewbie update your question with samples of what the data including characters would look like.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I've already did look at EDIT#1 in my question.

Comment: Is the serial always the last number in the string or all the numbers?

Comment: No it's not , Consider it as a very random number and just use the warehouse,code,original ID as indicator if you like , Thanks.